Can not create post in Prisma studio in nextjs. It give me an error while saving the post in prisma studio in nextjs
I do not where the error comes from but it is very annoying. Why Prisma studio can not save the post in database. I am using mongodb cloud database. Which I have setup in my environment file.
My schema.prisma file
    // This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mongodb"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Account {
  id                String  @id @default(cuid()) @map("_id")
  userId            String
  type              String
  provider          String
  providerAccountId String
  refresh_token     String?
  access_token      String?
  expires_at        Int?
  token_type        String?
  scope             String?
  id_token          String?
  session_state     String?

  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  @@unique([provider, providerAccountId])
}

model Session {
  id           String   @id @default(cuid()) @map("_id")
  sessionToken String   @unique
  userId       String
  expires      DateTime
  user         User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
}

model User {
  id            String    @id @default(cuid()) @map("_id")
  name          String?
  email         String    @unique
  emailVerified DateTime?
  image         String?
  accounts      Account[]
  sessions      Session[]
  Post          Post[]
  Comment       Comment[]
}

model VerificationToken {
  identifier String   @id @map("_id")
  token      String   @unique
  expires    DateTime

  @@unique([identifier, token])
}

model Category {
  id    String  @id @default(cuid()) @map("_id")
  slug  String  @unique
  title String
  img   String?
  Posts Post[]
}

model Post {
  id        String    @id @default(cuid()) @map("_id")
  createdAt DateTime  @default(now())
  slug      String    @unique
  title     String
  desc      String
  img       String?
  views     Int       @default(0)
  catSlug   String
  cat       Category  @relation(fields: [catSlug], references: [slug])
  userEmail String
  user      User      @relation(fields: [userEmail], references: [email])
  comments  Comment[]
}

model Comment {
  id        String   @id @default(cuid()) @map("_id")
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  desc      String
  userEmail String
  user      User     @relation(fields: [userEmail], references: [email])
  postSlug  String
  post      Post     @relation(fields: [postSlug], references: [slug])
}

Given below is the error in prisma studio when I save the post. It is very lengthy error.
Failed to commit changes: 
Invalid `f=e.match(KCt)?.[1]??"",g=e.match(YCt)?.[1]??null,v=e.match(XCt)?.[1]??null,{getPrismaClient:E,PrismaClientKnownRequestError:x,PrismaClientRustPanicError:D,PrismaClientInitializationError:P,PrismaClientValidationError:A}=require(`${c.prismaClient}/runtime/${u}`),k=e,F=(0,bq.createHash)("sha256").update()` invocation in
C:\Users\AB\naseerall\nextjs2024\lamadev\next-blog\node_modules\prisma\build\index.js:1969:10254

  1966       }
  1967     }
  1968   }
→ 1969 `}});return Ye.resourceList(a.workspaces)}};var ETe=require("@prisma/engines");var ZEe=require("buffer");function e_e(e,r,n,i){Object.defineProperty(e,r,{get:n,set:i,enumerable:!0,configurable:!0})}var t_e={};e_e(t_e,"serializeRPCMessage",()=&gt;L6);e_e(t_e,"deserializeRPCMessage",()=&gt;M6);var F6="PrismaBigInt::",$6="PrismaBytes::";function L6(e){return JSON.stringify(e,(r,n)=&gt;typeof n=="bigint"?F6+n:n?.type==="Buffer"&amp;&amp;Array.isArray(n?.data)?$6+ZEe.Buffer.from(n.data).toString("base64"):n)}function M6(e){return JSON.parse(e,(r,n)=&gt;typeof n=="string"&amp;&amp;n.startsWith(F6)?BigInt(n.substr(F6.length)):typeof n=="string"&amp;&amp;n.startsWith($6)?n.substr($6.length):n)}var hTe=U(u_e()),UP=U(eTe()),mTe=U(require("http")),gTe=U(nTe()),vTe=require("zlib");var Co=require("path");var bq=require("crypto"),cTe=U(hq());function vq(e,r,n,i){Object.defineProperty(e,r,{get:n,set:i,enumerable:!0,configurable:!0})}var lTe=globalThis,mq={},BP={},wf=lTe.parcelRequire1308;wf==null&amp;&amp;(wf=function(e){if(e in mq)return mq[e].exports;if(e in BP){var r=BP[e];delete BP[e];var n={id:e,exports:{}};return mq[e]=n,r.call(n.exports,n,n.exports),n.exports}var i=new Error("Cannot find module '"+e+"'");throw i.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",i},wf.register=function(r,n){BP[r]=n},lTe.parcelRequire1308=wf);var pTe=wf.register;pTe("9lTzd",function(module,exports){vq(module.exports,"guessEnginePaths",()=&gt;guessEnginePaths),vq(module.exports,"guessPrismaClientPath",()=&gt;guessPrismaClientPath);var $5COlq=wf("5COlq");async function guessEnginePaths({forceBinary,forceLibrary,resolveOverrides}){let queryEngineName,queryEngineType;if(forceLibrary?(queryEngineName=await(0,$5COlq.prismaEngineName)("query-engine","library"),queryEngineType="library"):forceBinary?(queryEngineName=await(0,$5COlq.prismaEngineName)("query-engine","binary"),queryEngineType="binary"):(queryEngineName=void 0,queryEngineType=void 0),!queryEngineName||!queryEngineType)return{queryEngine:void 0};let queryEnginePath;if(resolveOverrides[".prisma/client"])queryEnginePath=(0,Co.resolve)(resolveOverrides[".prisma/client"],`../${queryEngineName}`);else if(resolveOverrides["@prisma/engines"])queryEnginePath=(0,Co.resolve)(resolveOverrides["@prisma/engines"],`../../${queryEngineName}`);else{let atPrismaEnginesPath;try{atPrismaEnginesPath=eval("require.resolve('@prisma/engines')")}catch(e){throw new Error("Unable to resolve Prisma engine paths. This is a bug.")}queryEnginePath=(0,Co.resolve)(atPrismaEnginesPath`../../${queryEngineName}`)}return{queryEngine:{type:queryEngineType,path:queryEnginePath}}}function guessPrismaClientPath({resolveOverrides}){let prismaClientPath=resolveOverrides["@prisma/client"]||eval("require.resolve('@prisma/client')");return(0,Co.resolve)(prismaClientPath,"../")}});pTe("5COlq",function(e,r){vq(e.exports,"prismaEngineName",()=&gt;n);async function n(i,a){let o=await Gr(),u=o==="windows"?".exe":"";if(a==="library")return $a(o,"fs");if(a==="binary")return`${i}-${o}${u}`;throw new Error(`Unknown engine type: ${a}`)}});function VCt(e){return{models:gq(e.models),enums:gq(e.enums),types:gq(e.types)}}function gq(e){let r={};for(let{name:n,...i}of e)r[n]=i;return r}var Gb=(0,cTe.debug)("prisma:studio-pcw"),KCt=/^\s*datasource\s+([^\s]+)\s*{/m,YCt=/url *= *env\("(.*)"\)/,XCt=/url *= *"(.*)"/;async function JCt({schema:e,schemaPath:r,dmmf:n,datasourceProvider:i,previewFeatures:a,datasources:o,engineType:u,paths:c,directUrl:l,versions:p}){let f=e.match(KCt)?.[1]??"",g=e.match(YCt)?.[1]??null,v=e.match(XCt)?.[1]??null,{getPrismaClient:E,PrismaClientKnownRequestError:x,PrismaClientRustPanicError:D,PrismaClientInitializationError:P,PrismaClientValidationError:A}=require(`${c.prismaClient}/runtime/${u}`),k=e,F=(0,bq.createHash)("sha256").update({
         data: {
           id: "29789173273182",
           createdAt: "2024-06-29T19:00:00.000Z",
           slug: "firstpost",
           title: "firstpost",
           desc: "firstpost",
           img: null,
           views: 0,
           cat: {
             connect: {
       ?       id?: String,
       ?       slug?: String,
       ?       AND?: CategoryWhereInput | CategoryWhereInput[],
       ?       OR?: CategoryWhereInput[],
       ?       NOT?: CategoryWhereInput | CategoryWhereInput[],
       ?       title?: StringFilter | String,
       ?       img?: StringNullableFilter | String | Null,
       ?       Posts?: PostListRelationFilter
             }
           },
           user: {
             connect: {}
           },
           comments: {}
         },
         select: {
           id: true,
           createdAt: true,
           slug: true,
           title: true,
           desc: true,
           img: true,
           views: true,
           catSlug: true,
           cat: true,
           userEmail: true,
           user: true,
           comments: true
         }
       })

Argument `connect` of type CategoryWhereUniqueInput needs at least one of `id` or `slug` arguments. Available options are marked with ?.

Type: undefined
Message: 
Invalid `f=e.match(KCt)?.[1]??"",g=e.match(YCt)?.[1]??null,v=e.match(XCt)?.[1]??null,{getPrismaClient:E,PrismaClientKnownRequestError:x,PrismaClientRustPanicError:D,PrismaClientInitializationError:P,PrismaClientValidationError:A}=require(`${c.prismaClient}/runtime/${u}`),k=e,F=(0,bq.createHash)("sha256").update()` invocation in
C:\Users\AB\naseerall\nextjs2024\lamadev\next-blog\node_modules\prisma\build\index.js:1969:10254

  1966       }
  1967     }
  1968   }
→ 1969 `}});return Ye.resourceList(a.workspaces)}};var ETe=require("@prisma/engines");var ZEe=require("buffer");function e_e(e,r,n,i){Object.defineProperty(e,r,{get:n,set:i,enumerable:!0,configurable:!0})}var t_e={};e_e(t_e,"serializeRPCMessage",()=>L6);e_e(t_e,"deserializeRPCMessage",()=>M6);var F6="PrismaBigInt::",$6="PrismaBytes::";function L6(e){return JSON.stringify(e,(r,n)=>typeof n=="bigint"?F6+n:n?.type==="Buffer"&&Array.isArray(n?.data)?$6+ZEe.Buffer.from(n.data).toString("base64"):n)}function M6(e){return JSON.parse(e,(r,n)=>typeof n=="string"&&n.startsWith(F6)?BigInt(n.substr(F6.length)):typeof n=="string"&&n.startsWith($6)?n.substr($6.length):n)}var hTe=U(u_e()),UP=U(eTe()),mTe=U(require("http")),gTe=U(nTe()),vTe=require("zlib");var Co=require("path");var bq=require("crypto"),cTe=U(hq());function vq(e,r,n,i){Object.defineProperty(e,r,{get:n,set:i,enumerable:!0,configurable:!0})}var lTe=globalThis,mq={},BP={},wf=lTe.parcelRequire1308;wf==null&&(wf=function(e){if(e in mq)return mq[e].exports;if(e in BP){var r=BP[e];delete BP[e];var n={id:e,exports:{}};return mq[e]=n,r.call(n.exports,n,n.exports),n.exports}var i=new Error("Cannot find module '"+e+"'");throw i.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",i},wf.register=function(r,n){BP[r]=n},lTe.parcelRequire1308=wf);var pTe=wf.register;pTe("9lTzd",function(module,exports){vq(module.exports,"guessEnginePaths",()=>guessEnginePaths),vq(module.exports,"guessPrismaClientPath",()=>guessPrismaClientPath);var $5COlq=wf("5COlq");async function guessEnginePaths({forceBinary,forceLibrary,resolveOverrides}){let queryEngineName,queryEngineType;if(forceLibrary?(queryEngineName=await(0,$5COlq.prismaEngineName)("query-engine","library"),queryEngineType="library"):forceBinary?(queryEngineName=await(0,$5COlq.prismaEngineName)("query-engine","binary"),queryEngineType="binary"):(queryEngineName=void 0,queryEngineType=void 0),!queryEngineName||!queryEngineType)return{queryEngine:void 0};let queryEnginePath;if(resolveOverrides[".prisma/client"])queryEnginePath=(0,Co.resolve)(resolveOverrides[".prisma/client"],`../${queryEngineName}`);else if(resolveOverrides["@prisma/engines"])queryEnginePath=(0,Co.resolve)(resolveOverrides["@prisma/engines"],`../../${queryEngineName}`);else{let atPrismaEnginesPath;try{atPrismaEnginesPath=eval("require.resolve('@prisma/engines')")}catch(e){throw new Error("Unable to resolve Prisma engine paths. This is a bug.")}queryEnginePath=(0,Co.resolve)(atPrismaEnginesPath`../../${queryEngineName}`)}return{queryEngine:{type:queryEngineType,path:queryEnginePath}}}function guessPrismaClientPath({resolveOverrides}){let prismaClientPath=resolveOverrides["@prisma/client"]||eval("require.resolve('@prisma/client')");return(0,Co.resolve)(prismaClientPath,"../")}});pTe("5COlq",function(e,r){vq(e.exports,"prismaEngineName",()=>n);async function n(i,a){let o=await Gr(),u=o==="windows"?".exe":"";if(a==="library")return $a(o,"fs");if(a==="binary")return`${i}-${o}${u}`;throw new Error(`Unknown engine type: ${a}`)}});function VCt(e){return{models:gq(e.models),enums:gq(e.enums),types:gq(e.types)}}function gq(e){let r={};for(let{name:n,...i}of e)r[n]=i;return r}var Gb=(0,cTe.debug)("prisma:studio-pcw"),KCt=/^\s*datasource\s+([^\s]+)\s*{/m,YCt=/url *= *env\("(.*)"\)/,XCt=/url *= *"(.*)"/;async function JCt({schema:e,schemaPath:r,dmmf:n,datasourceProvider:i,previewFeatures:a,datasources:o,engineType:u,paths:c,directUrl:l,versions:p}){let f=e.match(KCt)?.[1]??"",g=e.match(YCt)?.[1]??null,v=e.match(XCt)?.[1]??null,{getPrismaClient:E,PrismaClientKnownRequestError:x,PrismaClientRustPanicError:D,PrismaClientInitializationError:P,PrismaClientValidationError:A}=require(`${c.prismaClient}/runtime/${u}`),k=e,F=(0,bq.createHash)("sha256").update({
         data: {
           id: "29789173273182",
           createdAt: "2024-06-29T19:00:00.000Z",
           slug: "firstpostnaseer",
           title: "firstpost",
           desc: "firstpost",
           img: null,
           views: 0,
           cat: {
             connect: {
       ?       id?: String,
       ?       slug?: String,
       ?       AND?: CategoryWhereInput | CategoryWhereInput[],
       ?       OR?: CategoryWhereInput[],
       ?       NOT?: CategoryWhereInput | CategoryWhereInput[],
       ?       title?: StringFilter | String,
       ?       img?: StringNullableFilter | String | Null,
       ?       Posts?: PostListRelationFilter
             }
           },
           user: {
             connect: {}
           },
           comments: {}
         },
         select: {
           id: true,
           createdAt: true,
           slug: true,
           title: true,
           desc: true,
           img: true,
           views: true,
           catSlug: true,
           cat: true,
           userEmail: true,
           user: true,
           comments: true
         }
       })

Argument `connect` of type CategoryWhereUniqueInput needs at least one of `id` or `slug` arguments. Available options are marked with ?.


Any one with some kind of solution here on stack overflow. I have tried chatgpt but that is also unable to figure it out.

Argument `connect` of type CategoryWhereUniqueInput needs at least one of `id` or `slug` arguments. Available options are marked with ?.

Since Category and also the User are mandatory fields, you need to create them first and then put them on the respective fields, since you're using prisma studio.
Also I don't know what are the consequences of mapping "id" to "_id", but I wouldn't do it

I have created the category and user fields first. And their values are added to the posts fields but the error is still exists and I am unable to save the post on prisma studio in my mongodb atlas database. What can i do?

I haven't used mongo in years, and never with prisma, but that errors reminds me of when I try to create an entity without the mandatory fields. Or when you change the db but don't restart the studio...
